# Ввод квадратной матрицы построчно

Tags: python, numpy

Как ввести подобное в виде квадратной матрицы? число строк и столбцов неизвестно

```
X_A  
XXA  
XA_
```

Для алгоритма нужно в таком виде:

```
a = [['X', 'X', 'X', '_'],
     ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
     ['A', 'X', 'A', 'X'],
     ['A', 'A', 'A', 'X']]
```

нашел вот это, но тут создается только одномерный массив

```
data = list(iter(input, ''))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно частично воспользоваться Вашим кодом. Получаете список строк, поданных на вход, а затем отдельно преобразуете каждую строку в список.

***Пример:***

```py
data = list(iter(input, ''))
matrix = [[c for c in s.rstrip()] for s in data]
print(matrix)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[['X', '_', 'A'], ['X', 'X', 'A'], ['X', 'A', '_']]
```

Comment: получается, чтобы закончить ввод нужно 2 раза нажать enter. как сделать чтобы ввод заканчивался после заполнения матрицы, ведь известно, что она квадратная. если что это поле для игры крестики нолики